# Failing to proceed to the next activity at button click

Tags: android

I am trying to open the next page at button click and at the same time store the values that have been input. But every time i click the button i get the message from the else statement. Where did i go wrong?

This is my class code:

```
package com.example.wirespeed_systems.k_mart;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextInputEditText mDisplayName;
    private TextInputEditText mEmail;
    private TextInputEditText mPassword;
    private Button mCreateBtn;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mDisplayName = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_disName);
        mEmail = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        mPassword = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        mCreateBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reg_create);

        mCreateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String display_name = mDisplayName.getText().toString();
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

               registerUser(display_name,email,password);
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerUser(String display_name, String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

This is my activity class code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_disName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/display_name" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reg_create"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/create_account"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When i run this code, it should store the information and open the MainActivity.

Comment: Do you get "Authentication Failed"

Comment: yes. but i want it to open the next activity instead of getting authentication failed

Comment: Can you show your dependencies please?

Comment: `dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}`

Comment: to know the problem, write this line after Toast


                                               " getTokenInterface.faild("faildIs: " +task.getException()); "

and see the logcat and search for faildIs, then print the error to know the problem

Comment: Please check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

There can be 4 possibilities for this:

**First One:**

Add this to dependencies,

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

**Second One:**

change:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                ......
```

to:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                ......
```

**Third One:**

Try to give a strong password, something like "JohnDoe@12345" because You have to meet google's password complexity standards.

**Fourth One:**

Check if you've added the Internet permission:

```
<uses-permission ....... INTERNET>
```

in your manifest.

Hopefully Something will work. Try and let me know.. :)

Comment: Have you tried latest dependencies version... According to the docs, your other coding seems to be correct, except the dependencies version.. please use latest version.

Comment: Also, check if you have added Internet permission.. Sometimes we forget that.. haha.. :D